# Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> query using linq

Tags: linq, dictionary

I have the below dictionary

```
        Dictionary<string,string> q1=new Dictionary<string,string>
        { 
        {"h1","name1"},{"h2","name2"}
        };
        Dictionary<string,string> q2=new Dictionary<string,string>
        { 
        {"h1","name12"},{"h2","name23"}
        };
        Dictionary<string,string> q3=new Dictionary<string,string>
        { 
        {"h1","name123"},{"h2","name234"}
        };
        List<Dictionary<string,string>> m1 = new List<Dictionary<string,string>> { q1,q2,q3 };
        Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> mhi = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>>();
        mhi.Add("x1", m1);
```

I need to return a list which has the values name1,name12,name123 using linq.
I am aware of normal method which works for me. But I am curious to know how to implement this using linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var q1 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"h1", "name1"},
    {"h2", "name2"}
};
var q2 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"h1", "name12"},
    {"h2", "name23"}
};
var q3 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"h1", "name123"},
    {"h2", "name234"}
};
var m1 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> { q1, q2, q3 };
//Using LINQ
List<string> result = (from dictionary in m1
                       from keyValuePair in dictionary
                       where keyValuePair.Key == "h1" 
                       select keyValuePair.Value).ToList();
//result = name1,name12,name123

//without linq
var result2 = new List<string>();
foreach(var dictionary in m1)
    foreach(var keyValuePair in dictionary)
        if(keyValuePair.Key == "h1")
            result2.Add(keyValuePair.Value);
```

**Edit**:
The `from` clause specifies the data source, the `where` clause applies the filter, and the `select` clause projects each element of the sequence into a new form.

Linq queries are not executed until we iterate through it. (Here `.ToList()` is doing that). It's like a blueprint which specifies how the information is returned when executed(iterated).

Lets examine each statement separately:

1. `from dictionary in m1` - This is much like `foreach(var dictionary in m`) except that it doesn't iterate (Because its a blueprint). It specifies which source we are iterating through (`m1`) and the variable to assign to each member (`dictionary` that is. We know that it will be of type `Dictionary<String, String>`)
2. `from keyValuePair in dictionary` - Here we use the `dictionary` variable created from the previous statement. The type of `keyValuePair` will be `KeyValuePair<string,string>` because we will be "iterating"  through a `Dictionary<string,string>` when the query is executed.
3. `where keyvaluePair.Key == "h1"` - This filters out the keyValuePairs from the previous statement whose `Key` property equals "h1".
4. Now that we filtered out the `KeyValuePair`s, we can `select` their `Value` property. This "projects" the filtered out `KeyValuePair` sequence to the new type `IEnumerable<string>`
5. Finally, `ToList` method executes the query to get the results.

Comment: Excellent that works.. Appreciate if you can provide some explanation.

Comment: Also in the abpve code I forgot to add this statement

    Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> mhi = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>>();

How does the linq query looks in this case
            mhi.Add("x1", m1);

Comment: I have added more information. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: About `mhi`, how will it be a query? Its not a query. You are creating a dictionary and adding some value ;)