# Building LINQ query to get List of Dictionaries from Dictionary of string/HashSet of Dictionary of String/String?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert one traditional logic into LINQ query (Method Syntax).

I looked at few questions already asked on this forum. One that came very close to my scenario is this: [Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> query using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055423/dictionarystring-listdictionarystring-string-query-using-linq). But I am still having difficulty converting my following logic into equivalent LINQ (Method Syntax) query. I need help. I am still learning LINQ, so please bear with me.

```
Dictionary<String, HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>> myData = BuildMyData();
String givenKey = GetGivenKey();
String givenValue = GetGivenValue();

// I need LINQ (Method syntax) equivalant to following logic:
List<Dictionary<String, String>> matched = new List<Dictionary<String, String>>();
foreach(KeyValuePair<String, HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>> kvp in myData)
    foreach (Dictionary<String, String> dict in kvp.Value)
        if (dict.ContainsKey(givenKey) && dict[givenKey] == givenValue)
        {
            matched.Add(dict);
            break;
        }
```

How can I build `matched` using LINQ methods syntax?

I tried following, but this gives me two errors -

```
matched = myData.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Where(dict =>
                dict.ContainsKey(givenKey) && dict[givenKey] == givenValue)).ToList();
```

But that gives me two errors:

- CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'bool'
- CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

What am I doing wrong? and How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to get the dictionaries in each Value:

```
 matched = myData
    .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value)
    .Where(dict => dict.TryGetValue(givenKey, out string value) && value == givenValue)
    .ToList();
```

Whenever you see a nested `foreach` the LINQ way is to use `SelectMany`.

Your query doesn't work because you are selecting the KeyValuePairs instead of each `Value`s dictionary and also because you pass an enumerable to `Where` instead of something that returns a `bool`(a so called predicate).

Comment: Thanks, I have got a lot to learn about LINQ. Can you explain difference between `Select` and `SelectMany`?